# Apache httpd : How to set header value on redirected request?

Tags: apache, nginx, httpd.conf

I am using apache httpd 2.4.34 and below are the httpd.conf configuration.

```
Header always unset X-Powered-By
Header unset X-Powered-By

## Header to set Server
Header always set Server "Server"

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule  ^/$ /login.do [R,L]
ProxyPass / ajp://x.x.x.x:8109/ connectiontimeout=300 timeout=300
ProxyPassReverse / ajp://x.x.x.x:8109/
```

Here I am removing the server token details from the response header and setting value as Server. On root request, if I will hit **https://example.com/** then the server will be going to redirect the request to **https://example.com/login.do** using the RewriteRule.

In the above-provided scenario, original server details are received back like below.

```
Server: Apache/2.4.34 (Red Hat) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_auth_kerb/5.4
```

For all other requests, it is returning below value as expected

```
Server: Server
```

How to remove or set response header value on redirected requests using RewriteRule?

Answer (score 0):

So I think what you are looking for is

Ref: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-For}i !^xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxx 
RewriteRule  "^/$"                 "/do.html"     [L]
ServerSignature Off
ProxyPass / ajp://x.x.x.x:8109/ connectiontimeout=300 timeout=300
ProxyPassReverse / ajp://x.x.x.x:8109/
```

skipping the server signature is less secure, but it sounds like you are handling things with security in depth. I hope this helps.

- Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

Use ProxyAddHeaders Directive https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxyaddheaders